# Toolbar using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am a beginner in JavaScript and starting to understand jQuery. I've written a toolbar that uses jQuery. I've also put comments based on what I understand of how the code works, though through the help of the book, it helps. But I would really appreciate if someone can review the code as well as the comments, so that I will know if what I'm doing is correct.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>JQUERY TOOLBAR</title>
    <!-- all stylesheet files -->
    <style>
        .tabStrip 
{
    background-color: #E4E2D5;
    padding: 3px;
    height: 22px;
}

.tabStrip-tab
{
    float: left;
    font: 14px arial;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 2px;

    border: 1px solid transparent;
}

.tabStrip-tab-hover
{
    border-color: #316AC5;
    background-color: #f9e391;
}


    </style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="tabStrip">
<div id="tabStrip-tab-1" class="tabStrip-tab">Tab 1</div>
<div id="tabStrip-tab-2" class="tabStrip-tab">Tab 2</div>
<div id="tabStrip-tab-3" class="tabStrip-tab">Tab 3</div>
</div>
<div id="descContainer"></div>

<!-- all script files -->
<script src="assets/js/jq.js"></script>
<script>



$(function() {

// keep track of the active tab's number

var tabActiveNum = 0;

// named function that will catch the event to occur
function handleEvent(e)
{
    // create referencing for both IE and W3C Dom
    var el = $(e.target);

    // Determine if the mouse was moved over or out of an element
    if ( e.type == "mouseover" || e.type == "mouseout" )
    {
        // 1. make sure to toggle correctly the tabstrip-tab-hover
        // 2. make sure that we don't add the tabstrip-tab-click, whenever
        // we hover to the tab 
        if ( el.hasClass("tabStrip-tab") && !el.hasClass("tabStrip-tab-click")  )
        {
                // make sure that tabStrip-tab-hover class toggled correctly
                el.toggleClass("tabStrip-tab-hover");
        }
    }

    // Determine when we click the mouse on the tab
    if ( e.type == "click" )
    {
        if ( el.hasClass("tabStrip-tab-hover") )
        {
            // make sure to track the tab index,
            var id = e.target.id;
            var num = id.substr(id.lastIndexOf("-") + 1);

            // make sure that the tab index is the same
            // as the tab content, if its true
            if ( tabActiveNum != num )
            {
                deactivateTab();

                // remove the tabstrip-tab-hover css
                // and add the tabstrip-tab-click to the element
                el.toggleClass("tabStrip-tab-hover")
                    .toggleClass("tabStrip-tab-click");

                // show the current number and tab description
                showDescription(num);
                // the num result set it to tabActiveNum
                tabActiveNum = num;

            }
        }
    }
}

// this function will show the description
    // of the current active tab
    function showDescription(num)
    {
        // create a div element
        var div = $(document.createElement("div"));

        // and append it to the div element with an id
        // of descContainer
        $("#descContainer").append
        (
            div.attr("id", "tabStrip-desc-" + num)
                .text("Description for tab" + num)
        );
    }

    function deactivateTab()
    {   
        // ensure we won't try to remove a nonexistent
        // object from DOM.
        var descEl = $("#tabStrip-desc-" + tabActiveNum);

        // if an element was found, use the jQuery's remove()
        // to remove the element fronm the DOM as follows
        if ( descEl.length > 0)
        {   

            descEl.remove();

            // remove the tabStrip-tab-click css
            $("#tabStrip-tab-" + tabActiveNum).toggleClass("tabStrip-tab-click");

        }
    }


$(document).bind("click mouseover mouseout", handleEvent);


});


</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Binding `click mouseover mouseout` to a single `handleEvent` function and then using `if-else` to distinguish the events is just silly.
Split the handling to multiple functions,
for example `handleClick` and `handleMouseOverOrOut`,
without `if-else`, and bind separately:

```
$(document).bind("click", handleClick);
$(document).bind("mouseover mouseout", handleMouseOverOrOut);
```

The result will be simpler and better.

The indentation is a bit messy, and you have a couple of empty lines at odd places.